# Is it possible to get a webhook/event at the user level for the Slack API?

Tags: token, slack, slack-api

I would like to build an app where users add a configuration and I can retrieve their user token so the app can act on behalf of the user.

I would like to be able to receive webhook events (much like if a bot user were in a public or private channel) whenever the user receives a message, is this possible?

A while back you could achieve this with a personal user token and hooking into the event stream via sockets but this has been deprecated.

Comment: Use the Slack Events API https://api.slack.com/apis/connections/events-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some snooping, they moved the User Tokens over to the same area as the Bot tokens. You DON'T have to do some weird configuration if the app is installed by you, you automatically get a new user token section.

You can then go to the Events section and subscribe to events on behalf of users.